# Wikidata Query Service - Bug on the 'Whose birthday is today?' SPARQL Query Examples

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

I was playing with the SPARQL query examples. The query ['Whose birthday is today'](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/SPARQL_Query_Examples#Whose_birthday_is_today.3F) always ends up in a QueryTimeoutException (Query deadline is expired).

However If I change the birthdate property P569 to the death date property P570, the query runs without throwing an exception.

Is there something to do to have the birth query successfully executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the query is possibly too heavy for the wikibase service. If you just try to get all the properties through the [person's properties](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:List_of_properties/Person), you will have success. I tried the following:

```
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT distinct ?name (year(?date) as ?year)  WHERE {   
    ?entityS wdt:P569 ?date .
    ?entityS wdt:P1477 ?name.
    FILTER (datatype(?date) = xsd:dateTime) 
    FILTER (month(?date) = month(now()))
    FILTER (day(?date) = day(now()))
 }
```

Comment: I'm trying to filter this for only returning actors and the query seems to take forever. Can someone help?

Comment: @German what are you trying to do? When it takes too long means you need to make your selection smaller. One way I suppose is to track down films.  PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT distinct ?name ?film ?film_name  WHERE {   
    ?entityS wdt:P1283 ?film .
    ?entityS wdt:P1477 ?name.
  
  optional{
    ?film rdfs:label ?film_name.
          
    filter(langMatches(lang(?film_name), "en"))
    }
 }

Comment: I need to adapt the query above to return only actors, so basically I want actors whose birthday is today

Comment: @German if you follow someone like https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q36949 you can find all the possible properties and then rewrite your query. SELECT DISTINCT ?name ?dob  WHERE {?entityS wdt:P569 ?dob; wdt:P1477 ?name; wdt:P106 wd:Q33999. FILTER (datatype(?dob) = xsd:dateTime) FILTER (month(?dob) = month(now()))  FILTER (day(?dob) = day(now()))}